# I want double hover css for my title

Tags: html, css

Actually, my title-text color is in black and the background color is in white. but I need,  when putting a cursor in the background its hover to blue and title-text color changes to white. Could you please help me.[image]

On Hover:
[image]

Comment: Share your code or link or what you tried before. No one just guessing from image

Comment: I'm guessing `.yourElement:hover{color:#fff;background-color:#00f;}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that text is inside your box ( a child ) , then you can do something like this. The below snippet should be used if you want to add different color to different texts

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.box:hover {
  background: blue;
}

.box:hover p {
  color: white;
}
.box:hover h1 {
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h1>Title will become red on hover</h1>
  <p>
    Some text Here will become white on hover
  </p>
</div>
```

If you want to change all the text color inside that box use `.box:hover { background-color:blue;color:white;}`

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution:

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.mybox {
  background-color: blue;
  color: yellow;
}

.mybox:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="mybox">
    <h1>
    Hello folks
    </h1>
    <p>
      what a cool website
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```